# How to decode a non-UTF8 encoded JSON array using Swift?

Tags: json, swift, decodable, google-suggest

I'm encountering some weird edge cases when parsing JSON data from the [Google search autocomplete API](https://google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=test). This is my model for decoding the JSON data:

```
struct suggestOutputModel: Decodable {
    let query: String
    let suggestions: [String]?
    let thirdValue: [String]?
    let fourthValue: GoogleSuggestSubtypes?
    
    struct GoogleSuggestSubtypes: Decodable {
        let googlesuggestsubtypes: [[Int]]
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case googlesuggestsubtypes = "google:suggestsubtypes"
        }
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        query = try container.decode(String.self)
        suggestions = try container.decode([String]?.self)
        thirdValue = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self)
        fourthValue = try container.decodeIfPresent(GoogleSuggestSubtypes.self)
    }
}
```

Most of the time this works. But when I query the API with `(` and attempt to parse the response, I get the following error:

```
Swift.DecodingError.dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to convert data to string around line 1, column 100." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around line 1, column 100., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=100})))
```

This is what the JSON response I receive from the API looks like:

```
["(", ["(x2+y2-1)x2y3\u003d0", "(", "(g)i-dle", "(a-b)^2", "(a+b)^3", "(g)i-dle nxde lyrics", "(a+b)(a-b)", "( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)", "(working title) riverside menu", "(working title) burger bar menu"],
    [], {
        "google:suggestsubtypes": [
            [512, 433, 131],
            [512, 433],
            [512, 433, 131],
            [433],
            [512],
            [512],
            [512],
            [512],
            [512],
            [512]
        ]
    }
]
```

There are some uncommon characters, so maybe that's the issue, though none of them seem UTF-8 incompatible? I also tried running `file -I` on the .txt file I received from the API when calling it in the browser, and it reports the encoding as UTF-8. In any case, the following test suggests the problem is indeed trying to decode using UTF-8:

```
let utf8Test: String = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)! // Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
let latin1Test: String = String(data: data, encoding: .isoLatin1)! // Succeeds, although some characters are represented in the \u format
```

So I then try manually decoding the JSON array containing uncommon characters (the suggestions) to String using Latin-1, re-encoding to UTF-8 data, and then decoding again to [String], as such:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    query = try container.decode(String.self)
    do {
        suggestions = try container.decode([String]?.self)
    } catch { // If undecodable, try converting data from latin1 to utf8 and redecoding
        suggestions = {
            let latin1Data: Data = try! container.decode(Data.self)
            let string: String = String(data: latin1Data, encoding: .isoLatin1)!
            let utf8Data: Data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
            return try! JSONDecoder().decode([String]?.self, from: utf8Data)
        }()
    }
    thirdValue = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self)
    fourthValue = try container.decodeIfPresent(GoogleSuggestSubtypes.self)
}
```

However this throws the exact same error I received before, and I'm now out of ideas for how to solve this. Would also appreciate explanations for why I'm encountering this problem - if the file I receive from the API is ostensibly encoded in UTF-8, why would decoding with UTF-8 fail while Latin-1 succeeds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question above is convoluted and probably way too long. Leaving it as it is because it lists a series of failed solving attempts and maybe that's useful to see. Below, I clarify the problem and explain the solution I eventually found:

**Problem:** Google has a publicly-accessible query autocomplete API that afaik isn't meant for public use. This API outputs JSON encoded in ISO Latin-1, even though [JSON should be in Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936869/17096282). Swift's JSONDecoder conforms to standards and assumes the data it receives is encoded with Unicode. As a result, it sometimes (but not always!) fails to decode the API responses.

**Solution:** Re-encode the data as UTF-8 and attempt to parse again, as shown below. For extra safety, obtain the actual encoding from the API response's headers (credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34687962/17096282)). In all my tests, it's always ISO Latin-1, but you can never be too sure when the API lacks public documentation.

```
let url: URL = ... // construct a URL for querying the API
let (data, response): (Data, URLResponse) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
var output: YourJSONModel
do {
    output = try JSONDecoder().decode(YourJSONModel.self, from: data)
} catch { // If directly decoding fails
    
    // Get actual encoding
    let encodingHeader: String = response.textEncodingName!
    let encoding: String.Encoding = String.Encoding(rawValue: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding(encodingHeader as CFString)))
    
    // Decode & re-encode in UTF-8
    let decodedData: String = String(data: data, encoding: encoding)!
    let utf8Data: Data = decodedData.data(using: .utf8)!
    
    // Try parsing data again
    output = try JSONDecoded().decode(YourJSONModel.self, from utf8Data)
}
```

Comment: If anyone knows how to build this get encoding-decode-reencode-parse sequence into a Decodable model, I'd still appreciate learning about it. Think that would be a neater / more portable solution.

Comment: Thanks for following up and posting a solution to the problem. I've never heard of JSON encoded in ISO Latin-1!